# Is there a way of reusing a string c#?

Tags: c#

I'm still a bit rusty on C#
I need to store words greater that 8 letters from a text file.
This is what I have at the moment:

n a new text file.

Comment: try stringBulider,or  simply newString  ="";

Comment: What about just `newString = "";` ? And yes, you should probably use a StringBuilder for performance.

Comment: Consider getting rid of `lettercount`, better use `newString.Length` instead. It will always give you exactly that same information. And it will reset to 0 (obviously) if you do `newString = "";`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this :

```
string[] words = fileString.Split(0x20) // split by space
IEnumerable<string> longerThan8 = words.Where(word => word.Length > 8);
```

Comment: A nice, simple approach. +1

Comment: ... it should be `> 7`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @PeterB Question was "I'm still a bit rusty on C# I need to store words greater that 8 letters from a text file" and `8 > 8 == false`

Comment: Why the cryptic `0x20`

Comment: Ah yes. Confusing, I based it on question code using `> 7`.

Comment: @GillBates Because everyone knows that `0x20 == ' '` and i like to represent chars in hex format

Answer (score 2):

How about you replace the entire thing with something like

```
foreach (var item in fileString.Split(' ').Where(t => t.Length > 7))
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `= ""` to reset it. Using `StringBuilder` would be better though.

```
foreach (char c in fileString)
{ 
    newString += c;
    lettercount++;
    if (lettercount > 7 && c == ' ')
    {
        Console.WriteLine(newString);
        lettercount=0;
        newString = "";
    }
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        lettercount = 0;
        newString = "";
    }
}
```

If you used `StringBuilder`, it would be something like:

```
foreach (char c in fileString)
{ 
    newString.Append(c);
    lettercount++;
    if (lettercount > 7 && c == ' ')
    {
        Console.WriteLine(newString.ToString());
        lettercount=0;
        newString.Clear();
    }
    if (c == ' ')
    {
        lettercount = 0;
        newString.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach (string s in fileString.Split(' ').Where(_=>_.Length > 7))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
```